# Values from dynamicly generated select are 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a table that dynamicly generates new rows and I need to get values from dynamicly generated selectbox. But all I get is `'undefined'`. If I try to get values from dynamic `<input>` then everything works fine. Problem is just with selectbox.

Here is my code that gets values from user

```
$("#myTable tr").each(function(index, element){
        if(index === 0){            // skip the table head
            return true;
        }
        var option = $(element).find("#course option:selected");
        if(option.val() == "-1"){        // should skip empty row but doesn't work either
            return true;
        }
        $(element).children().each(function(index, element){
            if(index === 0){
                activities[activities.length] = $(element).find("input").val();
            }else if(index === 1){
                activityIds[activityIds.length] = option.val();
                activityType[activityType.length] = option.attr("type");
            }
        });
    });
```

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/8rrmr/

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your addNewActivityRow function, you are not giving your select box the #course id. Actually, you should not use ids in this case but classes since an id must be unique for a page. Change the following line:

```
var option = $(element).find("#course option:selected");
```

to:

```
var option = $(element).find("select option:selected");
```

and it will work, but it would be best to remove all ids from your elements if you are going to have multiple instances of them

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that... I've changed "id" to "class" and edited addNewActivityRow to add selectbox with class .course and it works fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8rrmr/5/)

**CHANGE THIS**

```
 // can't find #course
 var option = $(element).find("#course option:selected");
```

**TO**

```
 var option = $(element).find("select option:selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
activityIds[activityIds.length] = $(element).find('select').val();
activityType[activityType.length] =  $(element).find('input').attr("type");
```